# How to scrape graphs (java) using coordinates M and L

Tags: r, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the underlying data of this graphs: https://www.wine-searcher.com/find/gaja+sperss+langhe+-+barolo+piedmont+italy/1/switzerland#t3

However, using `xpath //*[@id="highcharts-1u7r6pf-0"]/svg/g[5]/g[1]/path[2]` retrieves me the coordinates of each point. How can I obtain the underlying numbers?

I'm using R selenium

```
rD <- rsDriver(port = 3587L, browser = "firefox", version = "latest")
mybrowser <- rD$client
```

Comment: find the elements with this xpath `"//*[@id='highcharts-" + highchartID + "']//*[@class='highcharts-point']"`, and do a getAttribute("d") to get the coordinate values of the points

Comment: I don't want the coordinates but the values (the price of the wine) in an array. can you write an example of code please?

Comment: Try doing a foreach clicking every element returned with the xpath that i mentioned above, and do a print with the text on the notification popup (CssSelector: `[class*='highcharts-tooltip'] b:nth-child(3)`), i can also write an example in C# language if you want, as i'm not proficient in R...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't apply it on R. Is there someone who can help me with this??